# Iterating over a vector with foreach

Tags: c++, vector

The following code:

```
std::vector< int > keysDown;
    for each ( int currentKey in keysDown )
    {

    }
```

is throwing an intellisense error:

```
1   IntelliSense: a 'for each' statement cannot operate on an expression of type "std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>"
```

but it seems to compile and run, any ideas?

---

does not seem to iterate through the vector:

```
void Keyboard::AddKeyToVector( int key )
{
    keysDown.push_back( key );
}

void Keyboard::RemoveKeyFromVector( int key )
{
    std::vector< int > keysDown; // Placing this here for brevity, it's declared in the class's .h and is instanciated globally
    int i;
    for( int currentKey : keysDown ) 
    {
        if( currentKey == key )
        {
            keysDown.erase(keysDown.begin()+i);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's C++/CLI, don't use that. Use `for(int currentKey : keysDown)`.

Comment: Your compiler doesn't speak C++. It speaks some other language which often looks deceptively *similar* to C++ and has tricked many people like you into believing they have a C++ compiler.

Comment: @Xeo: It works in C++/CLI mode, but it also works as a non-standard exension in non-managed C++.  But of course, don't use it.

Comment: Hm actually, this does not seem to be iterating over my vector correctly? Does this work okay?

Comment: @JamesT: Your code declares a new empty vector. Remove the `std::vector< int > keysDown;` line.

Comment: Well, it's not actually there, it's in my class declaration, I make one instance of it global and reference it global.. I know I know, but still, it shouldn't be overwriting it.

Comment: Erasing from a vector invalidates iterators.

Comment: OH NOT ONLY THAT BWHAHAHHA, @Mankarse was right bwhaha, for this example I placed that code in for brevity, but I actually ended up placing it in for real bwhahahah. cheers guys, doh.